# make: Execution of multiple targets dependant on first one stops after making the first target

Tags: makefile, dependencies, chain, targets

I want to do following "stuff" using *make*:

1. Convert .pdf files within a folder to .txt files but rename their extension 
   from .txt to `.textfile`.
2. Delete their page numbers and save them as `.nopage` files.
3. Save all .nopage files into an archive. The archive's name should be `archive.tgz`.

My targets are: `textfile`, `nopage` and `archive`. `all` is supposed to do the same as `archive`.

Here is my code:

```
SRC=$(wildcard *.pdf)
OBJ=$(SRC:.pdf=.converted)

.PHONY: all archive trimmed converted search-% help clean

.SECONDARY:

help:
    @echo "$$helptext"

textfile: $(OBJ)                        
%.textfile: %.pdf
    pdftotext $< $@

nopage: textfile
%.nopage: %.textfile
    @cat $< | sed 's/Page [0-9]*//g' > $@

archive: nopage
archive.tgz: %nopage
    tar -c --gzip $@ $<

all: archive
```

Using the variables `SRC` and `OBJ`, I collect all the .pdf filenames so that `textfile` can start with the "first operation", on which the following targets are all depending on.
However, my Makefile stops after doing `textfile`. So if I'd call "make nopage", it would only create the .textfile files and stops there. Same for the targets that follow.

Any ideas on how I can solve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at these two rules:

```
nopage: textfile
%.nopage: %.textfile
    @cat $< | sed 's/Page [0-9]*//g' > $@
```

Yes, those are two rules. The first is the one you call; its target is `nopagee`, it has `textfile` as a prerequisite, and it has no commands. So after make executes the `textfile` rule, is does no more. The pattern rule (`%.nopage: ...`) is never executed at all.

Here's a good way to do it:

```
NOPAGES := $(patsubst %.pdf, %.nopage, $(SRC))
# or you could use NOPAGES := $(SRC:.pdf=.nopage)

.PHONY: nopages
nopages: $(NOPAGES)
%.nopage: %.textfile
    @sed 's/Page [0-9]*//g' $< > $@
```

And be sure to change the archive rule as well:

```
archive.tgz: $(NOPAGES)
    tar -c --gzip $@ $^
```

Note the use of `$^` rather than `$<` in that last command. Also note that I copied the `tar` syntax from your makefile; my version of tar won't accept that command, it requires "-f" before "$@".

Comment: So in the end, I'd have to create another variable?

Comment: @Two-Tu: You don't *have to,* you could work around it, but I think you'd be working toward the wrong goal. There's nothing wrong with creating a variable, if it makes things simpler.

Comment: Thank you! Worked that way :)

Comment: Oh btw, why is it `$^` instead of `$<` for the `tar` command?

Comment: See http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html  The variable `$<` expands to the _first_ prerequisite, only.  The variable `$^` expands to _all_ the prerequisites.